# VBA function creating a layer of 0 around the output range

Tags: vba, function, covariance

I've got the following Macro and Function working, but the pasted result has a layer of zeroes in the left side and top of the result. hope you guys can figure out the error in my code. I am to believe the error is in the function:

```
Sub AutoCovariance()

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim VarCovarOutPutRange As Range
Dim NumberOfReturns As Long
Dim NumberOfStocks As Long
Dim ArrayColumnsCounter As Double
Dim ArrayRowsCounter As Double
Dim ReturnsArray() As Double
Dim DataReturns() As Variant
Dim DataRowCounter As Long
Dim DataColumnCounter As Long
Dim Stock As Long
Dim dAutoCoVar() As Double

Set DataRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("DataTable").DataBodyRange

NumberOfReturns = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("DataTable").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
NumberOfStocks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("DataTable").Range.Columns.Count

ArrayColumnsCounter = 0
ArrayRowsCounter = 0
ReDim Preserve ReturnsArray(10, 1)

    ' Creating returns array
    For DataColumnCounter = 1 To NumberOfStocks
        ArrayRowsCounter = ArrayRowsCounter + 1

        For DataRowCounter = 1 To NumberOfReturns
            ArrayColumnsCounter = ArrayColumnsCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve ReturnsArray(NumberOfStocks, ArrayColumnsCounter)

            For Stock = 1 To NumberOfStocks

                ReturnsArray(Stock, ArrayColumnsCounter) = DataRange(DataRowCounter, Stock).Value
            Next Stock

        Next DataRowCounter
        ArrayColumnsCounter = ArrayColumnsCounter - 100

    Next DataColumnCounter

' Transfer ReturnsArray Data to DataReturns
ReDim DataReturns(NumberOfReturns, NumberOfStocks)
DataReturns = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ReturnsArray)


' calculate the autocovariance matrix
dAutoCoVar = Autocovar(DataReturns)

' write to the worksheet, for debug
Set VarCovarOutPutRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).Range(Cells(1, NumberOfStocks + 2), Cells(NumberOfStocks, NumberOfStocks * 2 + 2))

VarCovarOutPutRange.Value = dAutoCoVar

End Sub
```

And the Function

```
Function Autocovar(DataReturns() As Variant) As Double()
Dim dArrResult() As Double
Dim j As Long, k As Long

' redim the result array as a square array.
ReDim dArrResult(1 To UBound(DataReturns, 2), 1 To UBound(DataReturns, 2))

' calculate the autocovariance matrix
For j = 1 To UBound(DataReturns, 2)
    For k = 1 To UBound(DataReturns, 2)
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            dArrResult(j, k) = .Covariance_S(.Index(DataReturns, 0, j), .Index(DataReturns, 0, k))
        End With
    Next k
Next j
Autocovar = dArrResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds typical for wrong array indices.

Your array operations all assume that the first index is 1. But by default, if you ReDim an array like this:

```
ReDim DataReturns(NumberOfReturns, NumberOfStocks)
```

the indices will start at 0.

Try adding this line at the beginning of your module:

```
Option Base 1
```

This sets the first index of all arrays not explicitely declared as `Dim ar(x to y)` to a base index of 1.

Comment: @Sebastian: Did this help?